# WinForms: child form closes parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

In my C# project I have 2 modal dialogs (ParentForm and ChildForm):

In ParentForm I'm calling ChildForm:

```
        var ChildForm = new ChildForm ();
        if (DialogResult.OK == ChildForm .ShowDialog(this)) {
           ...
```

When I'm closing ChildForm the ParentForm is also closing automatically.
How can I prevent such behaviour?
Thanks.

Comment: This is not the normal behavior and the code you provided doesn't show anything that would result in such behavior. You need to provide more info.

Comment: Are you calling this code in the form closing event of parent form? it will be helpful if you can post the complete method/event where you are calling child form.

Comment: ChildForm called from button click handler
`var ChildForm = new ChildForm(); if (DialogResult.OK == ChildForm.ShowDialog(this)) { ... }` Both forms are modal dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So, the solution to my problem:** 
Some buttons on the *ParentForm* had the `DialogResult` property set to `Cancel` and because of this the *ParentForm* is closing after a click event is triggered.